# iPhone: plist with NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone

I have a pList in which I have 5 Dictionary items. I'm trying to read this dictionaries to array

```
NSString *plistPath = 
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pListName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSLog(@"%d", myArray.count);
```

But "myArray" all the time empty... What I do wrong ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: (Unrelated) `NSArray` does not have a property called count so DONT use it like a property :). [myArray count];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

should be:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

and

```
myArray.count
```

should be `[myArray count]` (As Joe mentioned)

Comment: Then there must be a problem in your plist or elsewhere

Comment: problem was in plist name...I don't know why, but name "coordinates" didn't work. So I rename plist, and now it's ok...Thanks for help in any way !!!